# Bootstrap modal: close current, open new with one html modal template

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I cant find solution for this. Use bs modal + slick slider and load content to modal dynamicly. Like this

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".mwrap").on("click", function() {
        var img, desc, value, elements;
        img = $("img", this).attr("src");
        desc = $("p", this).html();
        value = $("img", this).data("value");

        elements = $.map($('img[data-value="' + value + '"]'), function(img)  {
            return $("<div/>", { //get list of images for slider in modal
                html: $(img).clone()
            })
        })

        $(".wimg").attr("src", img); //add data
        $(".wdesc").html(desc);
        $(".wslider").html(elements);

    });

    $("#myModal").on("shown.bs.modal", function() {

        $(".wslider").slick({ //run slider
            dots: true,
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            autoplay: true
        });
        $('html').removeClass('.hide-slider');
    });

    $("#myModal").on("hide.bs.modal", function() {
        $(".wslider").slick('destroy').html("");  //destroy slider    
    })
});
```

How i can open another modal and close current by click on slider element?

[image]

Comment: Can you create a JsFiddle?

Comment: are you trying to close and reopen your modal after picking on the pictures?

Comment: why don't you just change the contents of your modal instead?

Comment: http://bogdan.tw1.ru/works project link

Comment: nice idea for change the contents, how can i do this?)

Comment: create a click event on your slider element. then get the image clicked and change your content. does your slider elements are related photos to the photo you clicked? are they more photos? not a different photo? or you are trying to create a photo slider of your album? like google image results viewer?

Comment: related photos filter by data-value